# How to load urdf.xacro in Pybullet?

Tags: python, visualization, robotics, pybullet

Usually in Pybullet we can do:

```
robot = p.loadURDF(os.path.join(urdfRootPath, "robot.urdf"),useFixedBase=True)
```

to load a URDF. Is it possible to load a urdf.xacro file directly?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load `.xacro` files directly using `loadURDF` function. Just like a bunch of examples showed [here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/122126/pybullet.loadURDF).